# Capacitive touch input robot to remote access iPad

Tags: robotic-arm

I'd like to buy a capacitive touch input robot in order to remote access my iPad but I'm having trouble describing a correct kind of robot.

I would like to keep lag down to an additional 60ms so that it is still a high quality interface.

I would like to have a robotic arm equipped with a capacitive pen that moves to places on the ipad screen based on the mouse or I'd like a array of capacitive pens that emulate the touch of a user.

I guess I'd use Squires software reflect and the mirror function but I'm open to using an SHD camera with the robotic arm and a pixel sensor array with the array of capacitive pens.

Does this make sense? How could I improve the design? What materials would I need to build it myself. Assuming ready built arm? How could I build an array of capacitive touch micro pens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the screen of an iPad is your desired workspace, and all the arm will have to lift is a stylus, this will not have to be a large arm.  There are many "hobby" arms built with hobby airplane servos that will probably work for you.  I won't list any makes / models because there are many out there.

I am not sure what your comment about lag is about, but if you want a fast arm, you should consider a Delta robot arm configuration.  Because the "standard" serial arms mentioned above are not very fast.  These are harder to come by.  the only hobby level delta arm i have seen was the [Robot Army Starter Kit](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1984252088/robot-army-starter-kit) on Kickstarter.

Comment: what about the other design with an array of styluses?

Comment: also would this work http://www.amazon.com/dp/B00HO15O54/ref=dra_a_cs_mr_hn_it_P1400_1000?tag=dradisplay-20 ?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the type of hobby servo driven arm i was talking about.  But you might be able to do better by making a custom 2D arm because you only need the arm to move in the plane.  (plus 1 bit of stylus up / down).

Comment: great, how slow would it be? who could I get to write the software?