# Device to generate screen tap response

Tags: automatic

I have extremely limited knowledge in the general topic of robotics and therefore this question is a shot in the dark. Please let me know if the topic is unsuitable for the site.

I am interested in creating a device that would generate a touchscreen tap. In a nutshell, I would like to replicate on a touchscreen the automated mouse functionality you can obtain with software like AutoHotKey in Windows. Since, without jailbreaking the phone, a software solution is basically impossible, it occurs that one of the first components would be a physical device that simulates a tap. Do any options for such a component exist?

I recognize that there are philosophical implications with creating such a device. I am assuming the entire conversation to be theoretical and solely related to the hardware design.

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in [this other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/2553/capacitive-touch-input-robot-to-remote-access-ipad) on the same topic, it should be easy to put a stylus on a small robot arm.  Note that since you don't need a lot of elevation difference, a [gantry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_robot), [Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_robot), or [SCARA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCARA) style robot is probably better than a "traditional" robot arm.